# Create Parent Child tree Employee Array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have this db structure of employee and position. i want have the parent-child model result is employee, but the relation parent-child is at position. this is my db looks like :

```
Pegawai (employee)
id | name | id_jabatan
1  | Bee  | 1
2  | Caa  | 2
3  | Duu  | 3
4  | Sue  | 3
5  | Goo  | 2

Jabatan (position)
id | id_parent | jabatan_nama
1  | 0         | manager
2  | 1         | leader
3  | 2         | staff
```

and want to create result array tree like this :

```
"parent" =>
   {
      "id": "1",
      "nama": "Bee",
      "jabatan": {
         "id": "1",
         "jabatan_nama": "Manager"
      }
   }
"child" =>
    [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "nama": "Caa",
            "jabatan": {
                "id": "2",
                "jabatan_nama": "leader"
            }
            "child" => [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "nama": "Duu",
                    "jabatan": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "jabatan_nama": "staff"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "nama": "Sue",
                    "jabatan": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "jabatan_nama": "staff"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "nama": "Goo",
            "jabatan": {
                "id": "2",
                "jabatan_nama": "leader"
            }
            "child" => [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "nama": "Duu",
                    "jabatan": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "jabatan_nama": "staff"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "nama": "Sue",
                    "jabatan": {
                        "id": "3",
                        "jabatan_nama": "staff"
                    }
                }
            ]
       }
    ]
```

I got confused how to create this with recursion. here is my code:

```
public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        $pegawai = Pegawai::find($args['pegawaiId']);
        $jabatanDibawah = Jabatan::where("id_parent", "=", $pegawai->id_jabatan)->get();
        $hirarki = $this->getPegawaiTree($jabatanDibawah);
        return [
            "parent" => $pegawai,
            "child" => $hirarki
        ];
    }

function getPegawaiTree($jabatanDibawah)
    {
        $hirarki = [];
        foreach ($jabatanDibawah as $jabatan) {
            $pegawaiBawah = Pegawai::select('id','nama','id_jabatan')->where("id_jabatan", "=", $jabatan->id)->first();
            if ($pegawaiBawah) {
                $hirarki[] = $pegawaiBawah;
                $jabatanBawah = Jabatan::where("id_parent", "=", $pegawaiBawah->id_jabatan)->get();
                if ($jabatanBawah) {
                    $this->getPegawaiTree($jabatanBawah);
                }
            }
        }
        return $hirarki;
    }
```

but the result is just first child of its parent. how can I add child of child to array result?

***EDIT 1***

iam missing this to tell. so actually I want the tree of specific employee, so i cannot use this

```
$pegawais = Pegawai::with('jabatan')->get()->toArray();
```

line and use this instead :

```
$pegawais = Pegawai::with('jabatan')->where('id',$args['pegawaiId'])->get()->toArray();
```

and also the default value of parent is null when it is on top level.

Comment: can you give the correct json? your given json is invalid.

Comment: thats not a json result. thats is object list

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPegawaiTree(array $pegawais, $idParentJabatan = 0): array
{
    $currentPegawais = [];
    foreach ($pegawais as $pegawai) {
        if ($pegawai['jabatan']['id_parent'] === $idParentJabatan) {
            $currentPegawais[] = $pegawai;
        }
    }

    return array_map(function ($pegawai) use ($pegawais) {
        $pegawai['child'] = getPegawaiTree($pegawais, $pegawai['id_jabatan']);

        return $pegawai;
    }, $currentPegawais);
}

$pegawais = Pegawai::with('jabatan')->get()->toArray();
$result = getPegawaiTree($pegawais);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/hQkSj)

The bottom line is simple:

1. our function gets all employees and the ID of the parent position (default is 0)
2. from all employees we find those whose position corresponds to the current iteration
3. we create an array of such employees
4. to get the child employees, run our function again. and pass the id of the current position, which will become the id of the parent position in the next iteration

**Edit 1**

```
function getPegawaiTree(int $idParentJabatan): array
{
    $pegawais = Pegawai::with('jabatan')
        ->whereHas('jabatan', fn($q) => $q->where('id_parent', $idParentJabatan))
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    return array_map(function ($pegawai) {
        $pegawai['child'] = getPegawaiTree($pegawai['id_jabatan']);

        return $pegawai;
    }, $pegawais);
}

$pegawai = Pegawai::with('jabatan')
    ->where('id',$args['pegawaiId'])
    ->first()
    ->toArray();

$result = [
    'parent' => $pegawai,
    'child' => getPegawaiTree($pegawai['id_jabatan']),
];
```

Comment: This answer is missing its education explanation. Please [edit].

Comment: thanks for help. but the array_map returns null. what should I check?

Comment: Left a link to a working demo, maybe it will help find the problem

Comment: ive edited my question @Vlad. another problem is, when I select specific row of employee, I cannot get the full array of its relation.

Comment: Added updated version